# Delcaration of variables without 'let', 'var', 'const'

Tags: javascript

So here are 2 snippets of code. Each one gives a different output.

### Snippet 1

```js
var a=1;

function none () {
    a = 2;
    return;
    
}

none();
console.log(a);
console.log();
```

### Snippet 2

```js
var a=1;

function none () {
    a = 2;
    return;
    function a() {}
}

none();
console.log(a);
console.log();
```

What makes the output differ?

Comment: hoisting.......`function none () {
    function a() {}
    a = 2;
    return;
}`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: What does the question have to do with `let` or `const`?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `var`, `let` or `const`.

Function declarations create a (hoisted) variable of the same name in the current function, just like using the `var` keyword.

The key difference between the examples is `function a() {}`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code snippet, `a` inside the `none` function refers to the globally declared `a` variable. So when you do

```
a = 2;
```

you are assigning `2` to the global `a` variable.

To verify this, check the type of `a` inside `none` function before the assignment.

```js
var a = 1;

function none() {
  console.log(typeof a);
  a = 2;
  return;
}

none();
```

In the second code snippet, you have a nested function declaration `a`. Because of [`hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), `a` inside the `none` function refers to the function declared at the end of the function. So in the second code snippet, when you do

```
a = 2;
```

instead of referring to global `a` variable, `a` refers to the locally defined function. So, you are assigning to the local variable `a` instead of the global variable.

To verify this, check the type of `a` inside `none` function before the assignment.

```js
var a = 1;

function none() {
  console.log(typeof a);
  a = 2;
  return;
  function a() {}
}

none();
```